Order columns based on suffix with dplyr and stringr
I have a dataframe that has columns that are separated out by suffix see ex_df. Each time I run the code there may be varying column amounts based on database entries so I am trying to find a way to organize it more intuitively. This means that when running my code this can actually get to be to _20 instead and would rather not have to edit my code each time.
#Df on how it currently is

ex_df <- tibble("address" = c("123 Str", "456 str"),
                "activity_1" = c("aa","bb"),
                "activity_2" = c("cc","dd"),
                "type_1" = c("11","22"),
                "type_2" = c("33","44")
                )

#how i want the df to look like
new_df <- tibble("address" = c("123 Str", "456 str"),
                "type_1" = c("11","22"),
                "activity_1" = c("aa","bb"),
                "type_2" = c("33","44"),
                "activity_2" = c("cc","dd")
                )

If it was always only two columns I would just do a select() or reorder(). And I do not want to use
select(order(colnames(ex_df))) because then activity would come before address and the issue would still not be solved.

select(ex_df, address, ends_with("_1"), ends_with("_2")) ?

@Edward this does help when there are only a handful or so but when I am pulling data there is no telling how many columns I will have since this is based on the database entries. Right now it has only _1 and _2 but it could go up to _20 so I am trying to find one that iterates it over and over no matter then amount of columns.

The fundamemental issue here is that your data frame is not tidy - because information you need (the suffices) are available only from the column names and not the values they contain.  Pivot your data into long format (as some answers already do) and the problem goes away.  I'd say it's better to address the cause, not the symptom.

helper <- function(x) {
  if (length(x) < 2) return(0)
  switch(x[1], "type" = 0.5, "activity" = 1) + as.numeric(x[2])
}

ex_df[order(sapply(strsplit(names(ex_df), "_"), helper))]

#   address type_1 activity_1 type_2 activity_2
#   <chr>   <chr>  <chr>      <chr>  <chr>     
# 1 123 Str 11     aa         33     cc        
# 2 456 str 22     bb         44     dd     

Another test dataset
ex_df <- tibble::tibble(
  activity_1 = c("aa", "bb"),
  address = c("123 Str", "456 str"),
  type_30 = c("00", "99"),
  activity_2 = c("cc", "dd"),
  activity_30 = c("hh", "jj"),
  type_1 = c("11", "22"),
  type_2 = c("33", "44"),
)

ex_df[order(sapply(strsplit(names(ex_df), "_"), helper))]
  address type_1 activity_1 type_2 activity_2 type_30 activity_30
  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>      <chr>  <chr>      <chr>   <chr>      
1 123 Str 11     aa         33     cc         00      hh         
2 456 str 22     bb         44     dd         99      jj     


Very clever solution. (+1)

This will put all columns that do not end with a digit (e.g., address) at the front of the data frame:
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

ex_df |>
  select(str_order(str_extract(names(ex_df), "\\d+$"), numeric = T, na_last = F))
#  address activity_1 type_1 activity_2 type_2
#   <chr>   <chr>      <chr>  <chr>      <chr> 
# 1 123 Str aa         11     cc         33    
# 2 456 str bb         22     dd         44    


You can pivot back and forth and take advantage of the names_vary argument.
pivot_longer(ex_df, -address, names_to=c(".value", "name"), names_sep="_") |>
  mutate(name=as.integer(name)) |>
  arrange(name) |>
  pivot_wider(values_from=c("activity","type"), names_vary = "slowest")


# A tibble: 2 × 5
  address activity_1 type_1 activity_2 type_2
  <chr>   <chr>      <chr>  <chr>      <chr> 
1 123 Str aa         11     cc         33    
2 456 str bb         22     dd         44 

This will now work for any number of suffixes. (Thanks s_baldur)
ex_df <- tibble::tibble(
  activity_1 = c("aa", "bb"),
  address = c("123 Str", "456 str"),
  type_30 = c("00", "99"),
  activity_2 = c("cc", "dd"),
  activity_30 = c("hh", "jj"),
  type_1 = c("11", "22"),
  type_2 = c("33", "44"),
)


Fails on two-digits, i.e. "_30".

Thank you this worked perfectly, I was just starting to use pivots to accomplish this but couldn't get the syntax right!

@s_baldur Hmm my data just updated to 8 columns. I will refresh data to get the two digits and reassess, thank you! I will remove it as the answer for now until I confirm.

@s_baldur My data went up to "_10 and it still worked perfectly for my case. Thank you Edward!

@JasminL0p3z in the OP you say: *can actaully get to be to _20 *. Anyway you can fix this solution by adding mutate(name = as.integer(name)) |> arrange(name) 

Jasmin, s_baldur is correct because R sorts characters as they appear, not as numeric, as intended. See my update.

In case there's a number at the end of names this gsub takes it to the front, which makes it rank after the zero-attached non-number names.
EDIT, added _ to make it easier for the regex to distinguish between mid-part and ending number
ex_df[, order(gsub("^(.).*_(\\d+)$", "\\2\\1", paste0(0, colnames(ex_df))))]
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  address activity_1 type_1 activity_2 type_2
  <chr>   <chr>      <chr>  <chr>      <chr>
1 123 Str aa         11     cc         33
2 456 str bb         22     dd         44


Thank you for this answer, I was hoping to stick with dplyr and stringr but this worked with the base functions!

Also fails on two-digits, i.e. "_30".

You can use str_detect() to extract the numbers after the underscore and use the order of these to re-order the columns. (Wrapped in a function here for reuseability):
library(tibble)
ex_df <- tibble("address" = c("123 Str", "456 str"),
                "activity_1" = c("aa","bb"),
                "activity_2" = c("cc","dd"),
                "type_1" = c("11","22"),
                "type_2" = c("33","44")
)

col_order <- function(df) {
  unique(
    c(
      # first get the variables not ending in a number - these will come first
      which(stringr::str_detect(names(df), "_\\d+$", negate = TRUE)),   
      # now the numbered variables (as.numeric to ensure 9 comes before 10)
      order(as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(names(df), "_(\\d+)$", group = 1))) 
    )
  )
}

ex_df[, col_order(ex_df)]
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   address activity_1 type_1 activity_2 type_2
#>   <chr>   <chr>      <chr>  <chr>      <chr> 
#> 1 123 Str aa         11     cc         33    
#> 2 456 str bb         22     dd         44

Created on 2024-07-18 with reprex v2.1.0
